# What are L/D ratio of famous WWII fighters?

Tags: aircraft-performance, wwii

I'm looking for L/D ratio of old warbirds. I'm particularly interested by the P-51D, the Supermarine Spitfire Mk.VII and the Mitsubishi A6M3 Zero, but I'm also quite curious about other warbirds that flew during this period.

What are L/D ratio of those warbird? The answer may include L/D ratio of other WWII fighters.

Comment: Interestingly, resource location questions are usually off-topic, but this can be made on-topic by steering away from "where can I find..." and instead asking "what are the..." which will no doubt bag you some references.

Comment: @Jamiec: I agree, many times I changed "where" to "what". More interestingly, it's because instead of a "bam <URL>" that may expire or "bam amazon link" that is of no help to a wider audience, asking directly for the problem is better. Even better, asking for why/how, e.g.: *How does the modern L/D ratio compare to WW2 planes and what led to the improvements, if any?*

Comment: @jamiec edited accordingly

Comment: Is a meaningful answer possible for aircraft that fly at a wide range of speeds and g-loads? For steady level flight, lift will equal weight and drag will equal thrust, but the drag/thrust will vary hugely between approach speed and max speed. Should we limit this to optimum glide angle, or some definition of 'cruise'?

Comment: Not a real answer, but you could try www.wwiiaircraftperformance.org it doesn't have the L/D ratios on the site itself but contains links to technical reports on the aircraft that may have that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the answers below from ["World war II fighter aerodynamics"](http://www.wwiiaircraftperformance.org/mustang/Lednicer_Fighter_Aerodynamics.pdf) by David Lednicer.

And L/D, of course, depends on the CL you are flying at but you can easily calculate it from the unambiguous drag area given

[image]

Edit: Calculated L/D vs speed curves below for 4000m altitude flight. A fixed span efficiency was taken to simplify the calculation. Please consider this as an approximation only

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 for the link to the paper, very entertaining.

Comment: How would one calculate the L/D from a given drag at unknown conditions, since both CL and CD are functions primarily of aoa.

Comment: I've attached a calculated polar for clarity. It's not hard to calculate these ones you got the basic aircraft geometric information such as AR, Wing Area, etc. Calculated L/D is for 4000m altitude flight